# PHP Soap Client and .NET Web Service

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

Hi everyone Im trying to consume a .NET with PHP using SoapClient but I got the following issue when my php client send the request, the .NET WS doesnt get the request xml on the right format heres my code i hope some one help me, thanks ind advice

```
class login {
    public $User;
    public $Password;
}

$logr = new login;

$logr->User = 'user';
$logr->Password = 'pass';


try {
    $client = new soapclient ("http://..../Service.asmx?WSDL", array('classmap' => array('LoginRequest' => 'login'),));


    print_r($logr);
    $client -> Login ($logr);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error!<br />";
    echo $e -> getMessage ();
}
```

when i test my .net webserver on a .net application i send this, and it works well

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLScheme">
    <soap:Body>
        <Login
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
            <LoginRequest>
                <User>user</User>
                <Password>pass</Password>
            </LoginRequest>
        </Login
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but when i test it on php i get this, and this error Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
        xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <Login
                xmlns="http://tempuri.com"
                xso:type="ns1:LoginRequest">
                    <User>user</User>
                    <Password>pass</Password>
            </Login>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the expected format by the service and what is the format being generated by soapClient? Also, can you see what the $client->getLastRequest() and $client->getLastResponse() return.

Comment: i edited my question with the results i get... thanks in advice i can do $client->__getFunctions() and it works well....

Answer (score 1):

```
class LoginRequest {
    public $User;
    public $Password;

    public function __construct($usr, $pwd) {
         $this->User = $usr;
         $this->Password = $pwd;
    }
}

$login = new LoginRequest('user', 'password');

$client = new SoapClient('http://..../services.asmx?wsdl');
$client->login($login); // try 1
$client->login(array('LoginRequest' => $login)); //try 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a .Net web service, using the NetBeans IDE, add a 'service' and point to the .net web service (make sure to put ?WSDL at the end), and then drag and drop from the 'service's ' toolbox to a php file and it writes the code for you :)

Works great too.

[I can't say what's wrong with your code though]

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue as well when helping a customer consume our .Net web service so I thought I would share in case anyone else came across this in the future.

Thanks to adudly for providing guidance that helped shed light on the issue. You have to provide a name for the parameter in the array, and note that the name is case sensitive.

**Working Code**

```
try {
    $wsdl_url = 'http://<mywebserver>/LeadWs.svc?wsdl';
    $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);

    $params = array(
        'lead' => ""
    );
    $return = $client->Insert2($params);

    print_r($return);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception occurred: " . $e;
}
```

My failed attempts used a capital 'L' for Lead. This is apparently the only thing in the WSDLs/XSDs that is lowercase by default. If you do a careful search through the WSDLs/XSDs you will see the exact names of any parameters your method expects. Once you get those right, `SoapClient` handles the rest of the XML encoding.

My final Code looked like this:

```
try {
    $wsdl_url = 'http://<mywebserver>/LeadWs.svc?wsdl';
    $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);

    $lead = new Lead(); // Could just be an array as well
                        // but I created a class to help the user
    $lead->FirstName = "Tester";
    $lead->LastName = "Test";
    $lead->ZipCode = "00000";
    $lead->NumberOfTVs = 2;

    $params = array('lead' => $lead);
    $return = $client->Insert2($params);

    print_r($return);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception occurred: " . $e;
}
```

Hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SoapHeader and setSoapHeaders [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php)

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how using SoapHeader and setSoapHeaders will directly answer the question?

Comment: I was wrong, I thought that the login was sent from the header, I think you need to pass an object of LoginRequest class.